# Targeting background image of div

Tags: php, html, css

I have the following code which determines the last image in my wordpres post

html

```
<?php
  preg_match_all('/src="([^"]*)"/i', get_the_content(), $images);
  echo $images[1][count($images[1])-1];
?>
```

I want the last image to be the background of this div

```
<div id="last-img"> ... </div>
```

Comment: You know you should really use html dom parser for this kind of stuff..It really makes things a lot easier

Comment: not sure what you mean, I'm not familiar with that method

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php
  preg_match_all('/src="([^"]*)"/i', get_the_content(), $images);
?>

<div id="last-img" style="background:url(<?php echo $images[1][count($images[1])-1] )"> ... </div>
```